# Join SQL tables on key where A.date is >=B.date1 and < B.date2

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, left-join

I am trying to left join table B to A where the date column, A.Date is between two separate date columns in table B, B.Date1 and B.Date2. Is there a way I can accomplish this with minimal operations or additional tables? I've attempted to run with something similar to below in my join but the query takes too long to execute. Additionally, I'm only expecting a 1 to 1 match between the tables in this instance.

```
Select * 
From TableA
Left Join TableB on TableA.Date between TableB.Date1 and TableB.Date2
```

Comment: I want to combine all rows from TableB to TableA where TableA.Date is between the two referenced dates on TableB. My expected result with my datasets is that only one valid row will match from TableB to A using this logic, though I recognize it's open to multiple matches.

Comment: If your question is about the query performance (is it?) please include the tables' schema, all indexes and the [actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: This is correct, but sometimes people make the 2nd row's start date be the SAME as the prior row's end date... which means BETWEEN is overlapping. You'd want to use >= Date1 AND < Date2. Also, usually there's a key you want to force equal like Table1.CustomerID = Table2.CustomerID

Comment: Also probably worth reading this. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common